# Limit of bounded sequence in metric space

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

I have this question that has been on my head all day and I could not find a solution that can convince me.

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $(p_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be bounded sequence in $X$ with bound $R>0$. Assume that the sequence converges with limit $p$. Then is the set $\{p\}\subset X$ bounded with bound $R>0$.

I have two equivalent definitions for a bounded subset of a metric space:
\begin{equation}
V\subset X\  \text{is bounded} \Leftrightarrow \exists q\in X,R>0:v\in V \Rightarrow d(v,q)<R
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
V\subset X\  \text{is bounded} \Leftrightarrow \forall q\in X:\exists R>0:v\in V \Rightarrow d(v,q)<R
\end{equation}

A sequence $(p_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded if the set $\{p_n| n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset X$ is bounded.

I can prove this if $X=\mathbb{R}$ with standard metric and with the second definition of bounded set with $q=0$.

I don't even know if it make sense for a general metric space.

Comment: Definition of boundedness in metric space is : A subset $S$ of a metric space $(M,d)$ is bounded if there exists a $R>0$ such that for all $s,t\in S$, we have $d(s,t)<R$. Maybe but maybe this can be equivalent to your first definition but i don't think so. Notice this is the logical thing to do because you only know the "distances" between objects in $M$ so what you want for boundedness is to set the distance between every element to be smaller than some number $R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\{ p_n \} $ is bounded with bound $R$ there exists $q \in X$ such that $d(p_n,q) <R$ for all $n$. Since $p_n \to p$ as $n \to \infty$, the second triangle inequality implies $$\vert d(p_m,q)- d(p,q) \vert\leqslant d(p_n,p) \to 0 $$ as $n \to \infty$. Hence, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} d(p_m,q) = d(p,q) . $$ It follows that $$ d(p,q) = \lim_{n \to \infty} d(p_n,q) \leqslant R.$$

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for. However, is there any formal explanation why $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}d(p_n,q)\leq R$ is true?

Comment: Yes, of course. Let $\{ x_n \}$ be a sequence of real numbers that converges to $x$. Suppose $x_n <R$ for all $n$ but $x>R$. Setting $\varepsilon = (x-R)/2$ in the definition of the limit we find that there exits $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $x_n > (x+R)/2>R$. This is a contradiction. Thus, $x\leqslant R$.

Comment: In this case $x_n = d(p_n,q)$ and $x= d(p,q)$.